# Crystal Reports: assign rolling value from array

Tags: arrays, crystal-reports, report, formula

I have two formulas

**@formula1** - placed and suppressed in details section

```
WhileReadingRecords;
stringvar array a;
numbervar i;
if length ({trips.SUP_SAME_PICK_DROP}) > 0 then (
    i := i + 1;
    redim preserve a[i];
    a[i] := {trips.SUP_SAME_PICK_DROP};
);
a[i]
```

this formula simply adds {trips.SUP_SAME_PICK_DROP} value into array.

**@formula2**

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
stringvar array a;
stringvar sh;
numbervar r;

for r := 2 to ubound(a) do (
    sh := a[r];
);

sh;
```

i want it to show value of **r** element of the array starting from second details row, while printing records. Like, if i am printing second row of the report, i want **@formula2** to show second element from the array, that is filled in **@formula1**.
If i am printing 10th row, i want **@formula2** to show 10th element from the array, that is filled in **@formula1**.

Now **@formula2** shows only last element of the array, when placed in details section. How to achieve my goal?

Comment: when I hardcode specific element from the array to be shown in **@formula2**, it shows it. Example `...sh := a[12];...` or `...sh := a[3];...` This means, array itself gets filled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

So all was correct except one thing
i have added into **@formula2** (very first row)

```
EvaluateAfter ({@formula1})
```

string and all went fine